# How to prevent URL from wrapping on two lines

Tags: urls, cross-referencing

I'm using the following environment on overleaf:

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
superscriptaddress,
nofootinbib,
nobibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{graphicx,bm}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{soul}
```

What I would like to do is to insert a URL to a page in a footnote:

```
\footnote{\url{https://github.com/author/long_long_long_long_long_long_url}
```

Unfortunately, the URL is too long to fit on a single line (two columns) and it gets automatically split over two lines: the first line gets a part of the URL while the second contains no ref. As a consequence, the URL does not point to the correct page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `hyperref` package the link will direct to the correct site

```
\documentclass[%
 reprint,
superscriptaddress,
nofootinbib,
nobibnotes,
 amsmath,amssymb,
 aps,
]{revtex4-2}

\usepackage{graphicx}% Include figure files
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
\usepackage{bm}% bold math

\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{graphicx,bm}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{xurl}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{soul}

\begin{document}

test\footnote{\url{https://github.com/author/long_long_long_long_long_long_url}}

\end{document}
```